# How to check if an enum item is defined for conditional compilation?

Tags: c, enums, compilation, c-preprocessor, microcontroller

I'm working on STM8 MCU and, unlike STM32, MCU's constants are defined as enum and not #define.

The fact is I need to know if enum value exists for conditional compilation.
For #define constant it is not hard as you can see with my STM32 code:

```
// code 1
SPCMD_arguments_T const all_mode_a[] =
{
    {"GPIO Mode", 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL},
#ifdef GPIO_MODE_INPUT
    { "in", GPIO_MODE_INPUT, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL},
#endif
#ifdef GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP
    { "opp", GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL},
#endif
#ifdef GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_OD
    { "ood", GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_OD, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL},
#endif
#ifdef GPIO_MODE_AF_PP
    { "afpp", GPIO_MODE_AF_PP, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL},
#endif
#ifdef GPIO_MODE_AF_OD
    { "afod", GPIO_MODE_AF_OD, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL},
#endif
#ifdef GPIO_MODE_ANALOG
    { "an", GPIO_MODE_ANALOG, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL},
#endif
#ifdef GPIO_MODE_IT_RISING
    { "it_rising", GPIO_MODE_IT_RISING, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL},
#endif
    { NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL }
};
```

But for STM8, all modes are defined as enum:

```
// code 2
typedef enum
{
  GPIO_Pin_0    = ((uint8_t)0x01),   /*!< Pin 0 selected */
  GPIO_Pin_1    = ((uint8_t)0x02),   /*!< Pin 1 selected */
  GPIO_Pin_2    = ((uint8_t)0x04),   /*!< Pin 2 selected */
  GPIO_Pin_3    = ((uint8_t)0x08),   /*!< Pin 3 selected */
  GPIO_Pin_4    = ((uint8_t)0x10),   /*!< Pin 4 selected */
  GPIO_Pin_5    = ((uint8_t)0x20),   /*!< Pin 5 selected */
  GPIO_Pin_6    = ((uint8_t)0x40),   /*!< Pin 6 selected */
  GPIO_Pin_7    = ((uint8_t)0x80),   /*!< Pin 7 selected */
  GPIO_Pin_LNib = ((uint8_t)0x0F),   /*!< Low nibble pins selected */
  GPIO_Pin_HNib = ((uint8_t)0xF0),   /*!< High nibble pins selected */
  GPIO_Pin_All  = ((uint8_t)0xFF)    /*!< All pins selected */
} GPIO_Pin_TypeDef;
```

So the code 1 doesn't work in this case.
How can I check if enum constants are defined and make my code portable on others STM8 MCUs?

Comment: The existance of those defined values depends on CPU type and you need to include proper header for that CPU to get the correct definitions. How do you decide which CPU header to include? You need to use the same mechanism to decide which CPU related values are available.

Comment: Maybe some C++ metaprogramming could help you out but I have no idea further.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible as preprocessor does not know anything about the C language and the enums. The actual compilation takes place after the preprocessing stage.

You cant use any C types, features or variables in the preprocessor #if s

Comment: So the only solution is to define constants with the same name and the same value in another header file ?

Comment: @AJT if you have to. I do not see any sense of the code1 on your question anyway. for me it is XY problem. But yes you need to have #define s for that

Comment: Well to briefly explain what is the purpose of my project. A PC sends a command via a serial terminal (like "gpio_config + <arguments>" to config a MCU's pin) and the MCU receives that command and do what it should be doing. My array "all_mode_a" permits to link an argument of a command to the MCU constant. For example, if MCU receives "gpio_config a 1 in"; it will check on by one if all arguments exists and then configure the pin 1 of the port A in input mode. Why using #ifdef in my array ? This code must be use on all STM32 families and they don't necessarily  have same modes.